# Team City build configuration for Continuous integration

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a team city build configuration , which picks up data from bit bucket and packages it to transfer to udeploy. There is no code build process , it is just simple package and transfer process. All i want is that my team city build configuration should pick files only which are newly committed and never been picked up in previous team city builds. How do i configure this build component to enable this feature.Appreciate you help !

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [Configure and Run Your First Build](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configure-and-run-your-first-build.html#ConfigureandRunYourFirstBuild-CreateaprojectpointingtoGitHub.comrepository) documentation.  The steps you will need to pay attention to are:

1. Setting the VCS Root.  This is how Team City will know when source code
   changes.
2. Automatic Build Trigger.  Even though you are not going to
   build code, you will trigger your "build" steps on changes in this
   repository.
3. Configure your "build" steps to do whatever packaging
   logic you need. You can add a [deployment configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/deployment-build-configuration.html) to deploy the packaged product at this point.

Comment: Got your point but i only want it to pick the changes which were not picked in last build.. currently it picks all the files present in the repository since first check in.

Comment: Keep the above and for the deploy step only Robocopy/CP files that have been modified or are new.

Comment: @user3899994: You can use `git diff` in the build step for your build configuration to check if there are any newly committed files. The git command you're looking for is `git diff --name-status HEAD^1 | egrep ^A`, i.e. "show the list of files affected by the last commit, and only show the newly 'A'dded files".